# How to get text of a TextWidget onTap

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a ListView which displays date in a Text Widget. On tap of the Text Widget I want the text in String. How can I get that?

Here is myCode.

```
 children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
         print('OnTapped');
         print(arrayDay[i].toString());
         // get the text of TextWidget here
      },
      child: new Text(
         arrayDay[i].toString(),
         style: new TextStyle(
         fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
     ),
```

Comment: use `ListView.builder` - it will give you an index you can use in `arrayDay[i].toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In on tap method you can get data from List. So i have post some code here so get Get more Idea

```
return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              return Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: ListTile(

                  title: Text(this.noteList[position].title,
                    style: titleStyle,
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(this.noteList[position].date),

                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint('Note Data '+ this.noteList[position].title);
                    debugPrint('Data '+ 'Here your Data Get'); // you can get data here
                  },
                ),
              ); // Card
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView.builder and pass the data in RowItem.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => RowItem( list[index]),
        itemCount: list.length,
      ),
```

and,

```
class RowItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  RowItem(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        print(data);
      },
      child: Text(data),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ListBuilder, pass the list inside listBuilder and get Data from current index on tap TextWidget

```
  child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return listTileCard(index);
          });

         listTileCard(index) {
         return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print('OnTapped');
              print(_list[index].toString());
              // get the text of TextWidget here
            },
            child: new Text(
              _list[index].toString(),
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            ),
          )
```

}